# Display welcome message with the username in php & mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a form for log in and log out .
My problem is when a user submit their username and password then display welcome message with that username.Files are given below.

include.php

```
<?php

session_start();


$host = "VKSolutions";

$username = "VKSolutions";

$password = "VKSolutions@1";

$db = "VKSolutions";

@mysql_connect($host,$username,$password) or die ("error");

@mysql_select_db($db) or die("error");

?>
```

login.php

```
<?php

require_once('include.php');

$error = '';

$form = $_POST['submit'];

$user = $_POST['user'];

$password = $_POST['password'];

if( isset($form) ) {

if( isset($user) && isset($password) && $user !== '' && $password !== '' ) {


$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `accounts` WHERE user='$user' and
password='$password';");

if( mysql_num_rows($sql) != 0 ) { //success

$_SESSION['logged-in'] = true;

header('Location: members.php');

exit;

} else { $error = "Incorrect login info"; }

} else { $error = 'All information is not filled out correctly';}

}

?>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<title>Login</title>

</head>

<body>


 <table width="80%" border="0"><form action="<?php $PHP_SELF; ?>" method="post" >
  <tr>
    <td><label>Employee Name:</label></td>
     <td><input name="user" placeholder="Enter Name" type="text" value="<?php echo     "$user";?>" /></td>
   </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label>Password:</label></td>
    <td><input name="password" placeholder="Enter Password" type="password" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input valin="right" name="submit" type="submit" value="Log In" /></td>
  </tr></form>
</table>
<?php

echo "<br /><span style=\"color:red\">$error</span>";

?>
</body>
</html>
```

members.php

```
<?php

 require_once('include.php');

if ( !isset($_SESSION['logged-in']) || $_SESSION['logged-in'] !== true) {

header('Location: login.php');

exit;

}

?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
<title>Staff Area</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="margin-top:50px; color:#00F; margin-left:50px; font-size:18px;             position:absolute">Welcome<?php echo "$user";?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

logout.php

```
<?php

session_start();

// if the user is logged in, unset the session

if (isset($_SESSION['logged-in'])) {

unset($_SESSION['logged-in']);

}

// now that the user is logged out,

// go to login page

header('Location: login.php');

?>
```

In my members.php it is log in but not display with username. I need that username.
Please find out what is wrong.
Thanks.

Comment: Set username in session too along with `$_SESSION['logged-in']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create `$_session` variable since HTTP is a stateless protocol. Your variables defined in login.php is not available to members.php unless you store them in session.

first in the login.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
```

then in your members.php file

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

will allow you to access it.

Answer (score 1):

Just use a session variable like `$_SESSION['user']= $_POST['user'];` and then display it using `echo $_SESSION['user']`.

Also make sure that you add `session_start();` at the beginning of the php file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your session username like this
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $_POST['user'];
then retrieve your session username to display username message
echo $_SESSION['user'];